# Making the side nav push content to the right when open (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, nav

I've been trying to make my page contents be pushed to the right by 300px (the width of the side nav) when it is opened, as in [this github repo here](https://github.com/robhern135/PrecedentTest).

I have contained all the content to be pushed in a div #content.

However for some reason this is not impacting here:

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("Therightnav").style.width = "300px";
  document.getElementById("content").style.marginRight = "300px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("Therightnav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("content").style.marginRight = "50px";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code,

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("Therightnav").style.width = "300px";
  document.getElementById("footer_container").style.marginRight = "300px";
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow-container");
  x[0].style.marginRight = "300px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("Therightnav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("footer_container").style.marginRight = "50px";
var x =   document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow-container");
  x[0].style.marginRight = "50px";
}
```